# Jquery scroll to tab module and open tab with anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tabs

I am using anchor links (on my main menu) to scroll to a tab module and open the correct tab.

I have some code that works well but with one issue.

If there is an anchor link inside the tab then the code will no longer scroll to that tab (although it does open).

[Test site here](http://tabs.ellbrandon.com). First 2 tabs have no anchor link inside and work fine. Last 3 tabs have anchor links and have lost their scroll.

Can anyone see any red flags or issues in the code that might be causing this behaviour?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.et_mobile_menu li a').click(function(){
$('.et_slide_in_menu_container .mobile_menu_bar').trigger('click');
console.log('done');
});
});
})(jQuery);

function _setTab(){
    // get current hash value
    var curHash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    // only continue if hash provided and scoped to member tabs
    if( !curHash || !curHash.match('my-tabs') ){ return false; }

    // split and int val tab num
    curHash = parseInt(curHash.split('|')[1]);
    // ignore if tab is current state
    if( curHash === window._tabSelected ){ return false; }
    // set current tab to window
    window._tabSelected = curHash;

    // add click event to tab selected
    switch(curHash){
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            jQuery('#my-tabs .et_pb_tab_'+curHash+' a').trigger('click');
        break;

        default:
            return false;
        break;
    }

    // scroll to tabs container
    _scrollToTabs();
}

// scroll to member tabs container with 50px offset
function _scrollToTabs(){
    var oTabs = jQuery('#my-tabs');
    if( oTabs.length > 0 ){
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: (oTabs.offset().top - 50)
        }, 1000);
    }
    return false;
}

// set falsey state for tab selected on load
window._tabSelected = false;

// attach to window load because the tabs functions are initialized later in document
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    // check for initial hash state
    _setTab();

    // add hash change window listener
    jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function(){
        _setTab()
    });

    // void submenu when we are in member section 
    var curPath = window.location.pathname;
    if( curPath.match('midtown') ){
        // only change hash and do not reload page
        jQuery('#menu-item-665 ul li a').on('click', function(e){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            window.location.hash = jQuery(this).prop('hash');
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Was not correctly calling the right div container in the click event;

```
// add click event to tab selected
switch(curHash){
    case 0:
      jQuery('#my-tabs .et_pb_tabs_controls .et_pb_tab_'+curHash+' a').click();
      break;
    case 1:
      jQuery('#my-tabs .et_pb_tabs_controls .et_pb_tab_'+curHash+' a').click();
      break;
    case 2:
      jQuery('#my-tabs .et_pb_tabs_controls .et_pb_tab_'+curHash+' a').click();
      break;
    case 3:
      jQuery('#my-tabs .et_pb_tabs_controls .et_pb_tab_'+curHash+' a').click();
      break;
    case 4:
      jQuery('#my-tabs .et_pb_tabs_controls .et_pb_tab_'+curHash+' a').click();
    break;

    default:
        return false;
    break;
}
```